# func paste(itemProviders: [NSItemProvider]) {

Tags: swift

I use the "drag" and "paste" functions of multiple imagesViews to multiple imageViews in the same application. As the function "drag" allows to know the imageView of origin, does the function "drop" makes it possible to know the imageView "target" at the end of the "drag" (coordinates? Tag? ...). Thank you for any suggestions.

// Right here, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) allows to retrieve the imageView of origin.

```
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {

    let touchPoint = session.location(in: self.view)
    print("\(touchPoint.x)")
    print("\(touchPoint.y)")
    //...

    guard let image = viewTaped!.image else { return [] }
    let item = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider(object: image))
    return [item]
}
```

// But with the function "paste", Swift knows the target, but can I and how to recover the informations of imageView_yyy? (coordinates? Tag? ...).

```
override func paste(itemProviders: [NSItemProvider]) {
    _ = itemProviders.first?.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { (image: NSItemProviderReading?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageView_yyy.image = image as? UIImage
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain the loading callback. By assigning it to `_` you are telling Swift that it's trash that can be discarded immediately

```
// This retains the progress
var pasteProgress: Progress?

override func paste(itemProviders: [NSItemProvider]) {
    pasteProgress = itemProviders.first?.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { (image: NSItemProviderReading?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageView_yyy.image = image as? UIImage
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Indeed, "pasteProgress" provides access to a huge tree of information. But can I find in this tree the identification or location information of the "drop" target imageView  (where I have to paste)? Thank you for any complements.

Comment: @jmz49 I'm not familiar with the drag and drop API outside of UICollectionView. Are you targeting iOS or macOS? I think you're implementing it a bit wrong if you have troubles accessing source or target data.

Comment: Thank you Oscar for following this conversation. About the question MAC or iOS, in fact I learn on a MAC, under XCODE, the Swift iOS language for iPhone (all up to date according to the latest versions). About your remark to be a little (if not a lot) wrong, I agree,  It's true, because I discover Swift. Maybe you can tell me a little more about trying to solve? Anyway thank you, it's nice of you.

Comment: Usually if things are hard, it's because it's wrong. Apple makes things very easy to do if you just do them the way they intended. I'd just watch or read some tutorials if I were you - it's hard to grasp how APIs are intended to use just from experimenting.

Comment: Oscar, Finally, I solved my problem by replacing the solution "paste" by the solution "drop". This function proposes, as for the "drag" function, a parameter "session: UIDropSession" which allows to retrieve the information related to the "drop". Thank you for your help :)

`'func dropInteraction (_interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {

// let dropLocation = session.location (in: self.view)
// print (">>>>>>>>> \ (dropLocation.x) \ (dropLocation.y)")

// ...
         }
         return UIDropProposal (operation: operation)
     }`

Comment: Yess, that seems more similar to the code I use in my collectionViews! Glad you figured it out!